# Explanation for weird positioning of blocks of variable height by CSS float

Tags: css, css-float

I am reading [this](https://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/) article. I came across the variable height blocks example. Please see the image.
All blocks have been floated left.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=2" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=6" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7" /></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Of the given rules, what rule explains the positioning of block 4,5,6.

Rule 9 clearly states:

> 9.A left-floating box must be put as far to the left as possible, a right-floating box as far to the right as possible. A higher position is preferred over one that is further to the left/right. (No translation necessary)

By this, shouldn't block 4 be positioned just below 1. 
Author also states that this is confusing. But never addresses it in the article again. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: *"“If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or **its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box.** Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.”* 2 is floated left, so elements after it will wrap around it's inline content. So 3 floats left, and since 4 can't go outside the container, it floats around 2, since the top of 4 isn't lower than the bottom of 2

Comment: @MichaelCoker I might have read your comment 25 times but no help. **...its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box**   . This condition can be satisfied even if the box 4 is just below box 1. I couldn't understand your last sentence: "So 3 floats left, and since 4 can't go outside the container,   _it floats around 2, since the top of 4 isn't lower than the bottom of 2_  " Floats around 2? Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: "floats around 2" a better word would have been "wraps around 2" - an element floated will cause the inline content of elements that come after it to wrap around the floated element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float "The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it"

Comment: this also pairs with the `clear` property in CSS. `clear: left` on an element that proceeds a `float: left` element will "clear" the left side of the element it's applied to, and will not wrap the floated element - it will go underneath it like you're expecting it to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear *"The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them."* So if you used `clear: left` on box 4, it will not wrap around any `float: left` elements that preceed it

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#float-rules), as quoted verbatim within the article (just before the plain-English paraphrases):

> 2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.

Since a higher position is preferred, by the time the horizontal position of block 4 is determined, it has already been positioned as high as possible, which is just underneath block 3. Since block 2 (being also a left-floating box earlier in the source) is now in the way, block 4 cannot move horizontally in order to be positioned underneath block 1, and so it stays underneath block 3.

Comment: If I make Box 1 half of its current size, then by your logic ("Since a higher position is preferred..."), box 4 would move just below box1. But thats not what happens. Right?

Comment: @SKG: No, because 2 is still in the way. As the remainder of my sentence states, "by the time the horizontal position of block 4 is determined, it has already been positioned as high as possible."

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by Michael Coker on the question is correct.

The article you posted does show a fix for this using `vertical-align`

In the most simplest of terms, the element will always try and float next to the last previous floated element. If it cannot, it will float as far to the left underneath it.

As element 2 is taller than element 3, it blocks element 4 from moving all the way to the left and therefore sticks it underneath element 3.

Float does not account for having rows, so it will always try and fit into the nearest available space.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my problem is, the rule stated by Michael Coker has two conditions. One of these can be fulfilled by placing box4 under box1. So what enforces box4 under 3? Your explanation is very helpful but I wish to go by official specs.